# Visual position of item in QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am working with PyQt5/PySide2. I Have a `QTableView` with `QSortFilterProxyModel` and the data is handled by `QStandardItemModel`.

I am using `QStandardItemModel.findItems()` method to find some cells in the first table row. The result is a list of `QStandardItem`s. Now I want to order these items by row in which they are displayed in GUI table i.e. the way that user sees them. Is there some way to archive this?. To translate proxy or model indices to to "view" indices.

I tought this could be done using `QSortFilterProxyModel.mapFromSource()` method but it appears the proxy indices do not have the desired order.

here is a minimal reproducible example written in PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from collections import deque
from random import randint


class Splash(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create model
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["column 1", "column 2"])

        # create sort proxy
        self.proxy = NumberSortModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        # create view
        self.table = CustomQTableView(self)
        self.table.setGeometry(0, 0, 275, 575)
        self.table.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)

        # create buttons
        button = QPushButton('Find cells containing 1', self)
        button.move(300, 70)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.table.search_string("1"))

        button1 = QPushButton('next', self)
        button1.move(300, 100)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.table._search_next)

        button2 = QPushButton('previous', self)
        button2.move(300, 130)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.table._search_previous)

        # fill model
        for i in range(15):
            self.model.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)),
                                  QStandardItem(str(randint(1, 100)))])

        self.show()


# takes care of the coloring of results
class _HighlightDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:

        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self._parent = parent

    def paint(self, painter: "QPainter", option: "QStyleOptionViewItem",
              index: "QModelIndex"):

        painter.save()
        if len(self._parent.proxy_indices) > 0:
            if index == self._parent.proxy_indices[0]:
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, Qt.red)
            elif index in self._parent.proxy_indices:
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight())
        else:
            if (option.state & QStyle.State_Selected):
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight())
            elif (option.state & QStyle.State_None):
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.base())

        painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignLeft, index.data(Qt.DisplayRole))

        painter.restore()


class CustomQTableView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.real_indices = deque()
        self.proxy_indices = deque()

        self.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self._re_sort)

        self.setItemDelegate(_HighlightDelegate(self))

    def _re_sort(self):

        # pretty print indices
        def ind_to_py(indices):

            py_ind = list()
            for i in indices:
                py_ind.append((i.row(), i.column(), i.data(Qt.DisplayRole)))

            return py_ind

        print("real  ", ind_to_py(self.real_indices))
        print("proxy ", ind_to_py(self.proxy_indices))

        real_ind, proxy_ind = zip(*sorted(zip(self.real_indices, self.proxy_indices),
                                          key=lambda x: (x[1].row(),
                                                         x[1].column())))

        self.real_indices = deque(real_ind)
        self.proxy_indices = deque(proxy_ind)

        print("sorted real ", ind_to_py(self.real_indices))
        print("sorted proxy", ind_to_py(self.proxy_indices))
        print("---------------------------------------------------")

        self.re_draw()

    @property
    def _model(self):
        return self.model().sourceModel()

    def re_draw(self):
        self.viewport().update()

    # we are always searching only in first column
    def search_string(self, string: str):

        indices = self._model.findItems(string, Qt.MatchContains, 0)

        # get QModelIndex from found data
        self.real_indices = deque([i.index() for i in indices])
        self.proxy_indices = [QPersistentModelIndex(self.model().mapFromSource(i))
                              for i in self.real_indices]

        # sort indeces according to their row and column
        self._re_sort()

        # update the view to highlight data
        self.re_draw()

    def _search_next(self):
        self.real_indices.rotate(-1)
        self.proxy_indices.rotate(-1)
        self.re_draw()

    def _search_previous(self):
        self.real_indices.rotate(1)
        self.proxy_indices.rotate(1)
        self.re_draw()


# custom implementation to sort according to numbers not strings
class NumberSortModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def lessThan(self, left_index: "QModelIndex",
                 right_index: "QModelIndex") -> bool:

        left_var: str = left_index.data(Qt.EditRole)
        right_var: str = right_index.data(Qt.EditRole)

        try:
            return float(left_var) < float(right_var)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass

        try:
            return left_var < right_var
        except TypeError:  # in case of NoneType
            return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Splash()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In short when I run the search and click next the red marked cell moves down. It moves up when previous is clicked. But when I apply sorting by clicking table header it is messes up next/previous funstions. I want the red cell to always go down irrespective of applied sorting when next is clicked same with previous.

[image: app minimal example]

Comment: You could put an image of what you get and another of what you want to get

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @eyllanesc. Code is ready to run and it should be obvious what I need from description when you run it.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of the painting should not be done directly but through the roles that must be used by the delegate to do the painting.

On the other hand, the following item must be selected based on the visual position of the item, so it must be mapped using the proxy.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
CurrentRole = Qt.UserRole + 1000
SelectedRole = Qt.UserRole + 1001

# takes care of the coloring of results
class _HighlightDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option: "QStyleOptionViewItem", index: "QModelIndex"):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        is_current = index.data(CurrentRole) or False
        is_selected = index.data(SelectedRole) or False
        if is_current:
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor(Qt.red)
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Highlight, QColor(Qt.red))
        elif is_selected:
            option.backgroundBrush = option.palette.highlight()


class CustomQTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.selected_indexes = []
        self.current_index = None
        self.setItemDelegate(_HighlightDelegate(self))

    @property
    def _model(self):
        return self.model().sourceModel()

    def search_string(self, string: str):
        # restore
        for index in self.selected_indexes:
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(index), False, SelectedRole)
        if self.current_index is not None:
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(self.current_index), False, CurrentRole)
        self.current_index = None

        column = 0
        match_indexes = self._model.match(
            self._model.index(0, column), Qt.DisplayRole, string, -1, Qt.MatchContains
        )
        self.selected_indexes = [
            QPersistentModelIndex(index) for index in match_indexes
        ]
        self._sort_indexes_by_view()
        if self.selected_indexes:
            self.current_index = self.selected_indexes[0]

        for index in self.selected_indexes:
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(index), True, SelectedRole)
        if self.current_index is not None:
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(self.current_index), True, CurrentRole)

    def _search_next(self):
        if self.current_index is not None:
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(self.current_index), False, CurrentRole)
            self._sort_indexes_by_view()
            pos = self.selected_indexes.index(self.current_index)
            next_pos = (pos + 1) % len(self.selected_indexes)
            self.current_index = self.selected_indexes[next_pos]
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(self.current_index), True, CurrentRole)

    def _search_previous(self):
        if self.current_index is not None:
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(self.current_index), False, CurrentRole)
            self._sort_indexes_by_view()
            pos = self.selected_indexes.index(self.current_index)
            next_pos = (pos - 1) % len(self.selected_indexes)
            self.current_index = self.selected_indexes[next_pos]
            self._model.setData(QModelIndex(self.current_index), True, CurrentRole)

    def _sort_indexes_by_view(self):
        self.selected_indexes.sort(
            key=lambda index: self.model().mapFromSource(QModelIndex(index)).row()
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense than my previous solution. I just want to point out 2 bugs for someone that might encounter this later.  In `search_string` method in `if self.current_index is not None` condition there should be `QModelIndex(self.current_index)` not `QModelIndex(index)`.  And there is missing `if self.current_index is not None:` condition in `_search_previous` method.